# Permission denied for some files, even with sudo and chmod 777

Tags: files, permissions

I've had multiple times that I wasn't allowed to edit a file. Even when I chmoded to 777 and opend the file with `sudo`. E.g. the file `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` in
[this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) tutorial.

First, how is this possible? Second, how can I get access to this sort of files?

Comment: The folders might be mounted with noexec.

Comment: Answer from user298372 was the problem for me. Be sure to mount your folder without noexec flag.

Answer (score 6):

It is not enough to have read permission on a file in order to read it. You also need to have read permission on the directory it belongs to. In the case of `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` the problem is `/sys/kernel/debug` which, by default, is readable only by root:

```
$ ls -ld /sys/kernel/debug
drwx------ 22 root root 0 Nov 20 18:25 /sys/kernel/debug
```

You need to `chmod a+r /sys/kernel/debug` to have access to the contents of that directory.

(I would not recommend it, since giving global access to `/sys/kernel/debug` is not a safe thing to do, but this is a different problem.)

The most common way to access such files is to use a root shell:

```
sudo -i
```